# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 Getx and Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, state, flutter-getx, state-management

When my app starts or restarts it shows me that error but when I do a `hot reload` it work fine.
I am retrieving data from `firebase`, and I am using `getx` as state management, so what I thinking about when I get the data it may be takes few milliseconds to get the data, during these few milliseconds it returns null so that error appears until I save it again(which means `hot reload`) and it go back to normal state.
This is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:halwa_app/src/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:halwa_app/src/controllers/merchatntcontroller.dart';
import 'package:halwa_app/src/shared/backgroundWidget.dart';
import 'package:halwa_app/src/views/merchant_screens/product_screen/add.dart';

class MerchantHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   MerchantHomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final merchantController = Get.find<MerchantController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: CustomBackground(
        bgColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "DASHBOARD",
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .bodyText2
                  ?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 25),
            ),
            const Divider(
              thickness: 2,
              indent: 30,
              endIndent: 30,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: ligthBg, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: RichText(
                      maxLines: 2,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      text: TextSpan(
                          text:"${2}" ,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                          children: [
                             TextSpan(text: "\n"),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: "TOTAL PRODUCTS",
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                            )
                          ]),
                    ),

                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: ligthBg, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: RichText(
                    maxLines: 2,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    text: TextSpan(
                        text: "50",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                        children: [
                          const TextSpan(text: "\n"),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: "TOTAL ORDERS",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                          )
                        ]),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 20,
                  right: 20,
                  top: 20,
                ),
                child: Obx(
                  ()=> GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate:  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                      childAspectRatio: 0.9,
                    ),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount:  merchantController.productList.length+1,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    physics:  BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      print(merchantController.productList.isEmpty);

                        return (index == 0)
                            ? InkWell(
                          onTap: () => Get.to(() => AddProduct()),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: kPrimary),
                              color: ligthBg,
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.add_circle_outline_rounded,
                              color: kSecondary,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                            : InkWell(
                          onTap: (){ Get.to(() => AddProduct(product: merchantController.productList[index-1],));
                          print(merchantController.productList.isEmpty);
                          },

                          /// index will be replcaed with product modal from products list
                          /// for eg . productsList[index]
                          ///
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: kPrimary),
                              // image: DecorationImage(
                              //   image: NetworkImage(
                              //     "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Algerian_Baklawa.jpg",
                              //   ),
                              //   fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              // ),
                            ),
                            child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                              placeholder: "assets/images/placeholder.png",
                              image:
                              "https://images.ctfassets.net/lzny33ho1g45/T5qqQQVznbZaNyxmHybDT/b76e0ff25a495e00647fa9fa6193a3c2/best-url-shorteners-00-hero.png?w=1520&fm=jpg&q=30&fit=thumb&h=760"/*merchantController.productList[index-1]!.images![0]*/,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this part of my controller :

```
/*-------------------------------get product----------------------------------*/
  Rx<List<Product?>> _obsProduct = Rx<List<Product?>>([]);
  List<Product?> get productList => _obsProduct.value;
  List<Product?> fetchProduct(QuerySnapshot querySnapshot){
    return querySnapshot.docs.map((product) {
      return Product.fromFirebase(product);
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<Product?>> productsStream() {
    return productsCollRef.where('merchant_id', isEqualTo: userID).snapshots().map(fetchProduct);
  }
  /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: change `itemCount:  merchantController.productList.length+1,` to `itemCount: merchantController.productList.length,` (remove the '+1'). If it still fails, then point out where exactly in your first code does it fail and add the results of your print statements.

Comment: as peter said try it (remove +1), and other thing would be using FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder, after implementing one of those you get connectionState for snapshot, check if connectionState.waiting return a circular loading indicator then in next statement check if snapshot.hasData inside this block return the UI with the data.